# How to get work this complicated query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is my database schema:

```
Post:
id
title
body
date

Tag:
id
title

Post_Tag:
id
id_post
id_tag

Comment:
id
id_post
body
date
```

and this is the query to show post with all associated tags and the comments's number.

```
SELECT
    p.ID,
    p.title,
    p.body,
    p.c_date,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT_WS('|', CAST(t.ID AS CHAR), t.title) SEPARATOR ';') AS tags,
    COUNT(c.ID) AS comments
FROM Post p
    LEFT JOIN Comment c ON p.ID = c.id_post
    LEFT JOIN Post_Tag pt ON p.ID = pt.id_post
    LEFT JOIN Tag t ON pt.id_tag = t.ID
GROUP BY p.ID, p.title, p.body, p.c_date
ORDER BY p.c_date DESC
```

The problem is that the **comments's number is wrong**.

If the post is in 3 tags and there is 1 comment, then it show me that there are 3 comments and not only 1.

So it show me (comments's number)*(associated tags's number) comments.

How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT c.ID) AS comments` works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT c.ID)` instead of `COUNT(c.ID)`:

```
SELECT
    p.ID,
    p.title,
    p.body,
    p.c_date,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT_WS('|', 
                                    CAST(t.ID AS CHAR), 
                                    t.title) SEPARATOR ';') AS tags,
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.ID) AS comments
FROM Post p
    LEFT JOIN Comment  AS c  ON p.ID      = c.id_post
    LEFT JOIN Post_Tag AS pt ON p.ID      = pt.id_post
    LEFT JOIN Tag      AS  t ON pt.id_tag = t.ID
GROUP BY p.ID, 
         p.title, 
         p.body, 
         p.c_date;
ORDER BY p.c_date DESC
```